# jQuery fadeout question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering how i can fadeout a class element in jQuery. I've got a list of div's and all of them got the same class name. So, if i click on of them, all fades out. How can i make it so just the one I'm clicking is fading out?

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.imageWrap').click(function() {
               $(this).fadeOut();
           }
        });
```

I've been checking the jquery docs but i can't find any solutions too this. I know it's a basic question but i hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted will do exactly that, except you're missing a closing `);` after the `click` handler.

Answer (score 2):

This will work as you expect it but you have a typo:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.imageWrap').click(function() {
           $(this).fadeOut();
       }); // < - missing parathesis and semicolon
    });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NTtqx/

Comment: *"missing parathesis"* **And** semicolon. Never rely on the horror that is automatic semicolon insertion.

Answer (score 0):

That code you have above should be fading just the image you click on out, he `$(this)` part selects just the image that has been clicked on and then fades it out, your issue is the typo, you've got a missing `)`:

```
$('.imageWrap').click(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut();
}) //ADD THE CLOSING BRACKET HERE
```

I've pretty much copied your code line for line in this JSFiddle and as you can see when you click on one div just that div fades out: http://jsfiddle.net/SMtuG/, so it's clearly just the typo causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close 'click' event with '});':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.imageWrap').click(function() {
       $(this).fadeOut();
   });
});
```